# ModX. Apache2. Сайт выдает 500 ответ сервера при добавлении в apache2.conf строки AllowOverride None

Tags: .htaccess, modx, apache2

У меня проблема с тем, что Apache2 игнорирует файл .htaccess. Чтобы это исправить, я изменила

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

На

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

То бишь поставила All вместо None, чтоб апач видел .htaccess. Перезапустила апач, но теперь сайт выдает Internal Server Error
Сделала предположение, что ошибка в самих файлах .htaccess. Но эти файлы были в установочной директории ModX.
Вот .htaccess из корневой директории

```
# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. You must serve web
# pages via Apache with mod_rewrite to use this functionality, and you must
# change the file name from ht.access to .htaccess.
#
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
# E.g., "/modx" if your installation is in a "modx" subdirectory.
#
# You may choose to make your URLs non-case-sensitive by adding a NC directive
# to your rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Prevent rewrite the .well-known directory used by LetsEncrypt by rules below of this rule
RewriteRule "^\.well-known/" - [L]


# Prevent dot directories (hidden directories like .git) to be exposed to the public
# Except for the .well-known directory used by LetsEncrypt a.o
RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]


# Rewrite www.example.com -> example.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# or for the opposite example.com -> www.example.com use the following
# DO NOT USE BOTH
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L] .


# Force rewrite to https for every host
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# Redirect the manager to a specific domain - don't rename the ht.access file
# in the manager folder to use this this rule
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/manager [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]


# For servers that support output compression, you should pick up a bit of
# speed by un-commenting the following lines.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Вот из core:

```
# deny access to _all_ files in the core, including changelog.txt and error.log
# original borrowed from owncloud

# line below if for Apache 2.4
<ifModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</ifModule>

# line below if for Apache 2.2
<ifModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    deny from all
    Satisfy All
</ifModule>

# section for Apache 2.2 and 2.4
IndexIgnore *
```

В чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: Читайте ошибку в логах ошибок apache2

Comment: Значит по какой-то причине оказался не включен модуль mod_rewrite

Comment: @andreymal вот что там написано "/var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration,"  
Но у меня в .htaccess, связанного с этой командой только "RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /"
Что тут неверно?

Comment: @andreymal да, вы правы абсолютно, включила - все заработало. Спасибо, вопрос решился